# Showing border for columns in barchart of chart js on hover?

Tags: javascript, hover, chart.js, border

Is it possible to show a border color around each columns of a bar chart drawn using chart js while hovering on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `hoverBorderWidth` on your `dataset` as shown in the code below:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First Dataset",
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)"],
      borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)"],
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBorderWidth: 5
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="80"></canvas>
```